# When should I Build a full stack project which only will be used internally.(without network connection)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, build

I was having a conversation with my senior about our project and I've got a question without any clear answers. This is our first web project so no one knows why and how to build when the product will be only used internally.

I thought just making backend and frontend separately and run each of them to use it. Our product will be installed in governments' buildings where Internet is not allowed, so it will not be connected to the Internet never, ever. So I planned just making axios http requests to communicate with backend server. However, My senior said I have to build the project and He didn't explain 'why'.

Basically, we're using nodejs(express) backend, vuejs frontend.
He wants to sync the backend and frontend by adding vue.config.js as follow.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 publicPath: '../backend/public'
}
```

then just simply run 'npm run build'

but.... why?? We get the backend data using axios anyway...

Does anyone have a clear answer for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why is a build step required?

A build step allows the use of a toolchain. In today's (2020) world this generally means Webpack. Non-exhaustive list of benefits of this approach:

- Minification (make your javascript files smaller)
- Transpilation/backporting and polyfill addition (make your javascript compatible with older browsers, even if you use newer javascript features)
- CSS post- and pre-processing (make your CSS compatible with older browsers or use a CSS pre-processor like SASS)
- Simpler dependency management (can use `npm` to manage dependencies instead of hardcoding `<script>` tags in every HTML file)

Webpack is a bundler, which in itself is also a benefit, just one that is harder to explain to someone who's never used a bundler. Here is a link [explaining some of the benefits](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/1183/what-does-webpack-do-and-how-do-i-use-it-for-my-website/).